# Call Variable Function from External JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to call the function outside js file, but that function is declared in variable, something like this below

> external.js is the third party library which i shouldn't edit

```
jQuery(function(){
  var submit_clicked={
    cart_submit: function() {
     alert("yes variable function is have scope outside");
    }
  }

});
```

In my side i call internal javascript something like

```
jQuery(function() {
  alert(submit_clicked.cart_submit);
});
```

it denotes

> Reference Error: submit_clicked is not defined

not sure how to overcome this issue. Can anyone suggest some ideas will be great :)

Here is my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/rr2v4fhb/

FYI: I call my script next to the external js but still that scope is not available.

Comment: Define the `submit_clicked` function *outside* of the jQuery ready handler function in your external file. If you have multiple files which all need to access each others variables, you should look in to creating your own namespace.

Comment: Do you know what local and global variables mean? [Look into JS modules](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc#.sap2mg3ug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the external.js file. Declare the variable outside the `jquery()` handler and that should solve your issue!

If the external file is non-editable, then you cannot access the variable function due to its scope which is local (what you need is a global variable).